# iter() returned non-iterator of type 'dict_items'

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

This is driving me insane.  Below is a `class` I was messing around with, the goal was to have a way to support dynamic attribute assignment.  *Please forget for a moment the poor implementation or why I didn't just use a dictionary*, I know there are other ways to do this (such as `Enum`) but this was my test code before and now it became my quest to find out why it's not working.

```
class Family(object):
    def children(self):
        return self.__dict__.values()

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.__dict__[key] = value

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.__dict__[item]

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.__dict__)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.__dict__.items()
```

This all seems fine, and I initiated a test object as follows:

```
foo = Family()
foo.a = 'foo'
foo.b = 'bar'

[i for i in foo]
```

Now the expected outcome was `[('a', 'foo'), ('b', 'bar')]`, but what I got was this instead:

> `TypeError: iter() returned non-iterator of type 'dict_items'`

I thought I might have messed up the `__iter__` method, so I checked as follow:

```
type(foo.__iter__())
# <class 'dict_items'>
type(foo.__dict__.items())
# <class 'dict_items'>

[i for i in foo.__dict.__items()]
# [('a', 'foo'), ('b', 'bar')]

foo.__dict__.items() == foo.__iter__()
# True
```

If they're both identical, why doesn't `[i for i in foo]` work?

Comment: BTW, for completeness, you should also define a [`__delitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__delitem__) method.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What about this:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return iter(self.__dict__.items())
```

Python wants an `iterator`, not a `list` (or other list-like/dict-like object)

Remember: a `list` or `dict` is not an `iterator`, an `iterator` is usually (for easy-understanding) a pointer (cursor) pointing to an item of the `list` or `dict`.

Comment: FWIW, in Python 3, `dict.items()` returns a [view object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects), not a list.

Comment: This worked.  I thought I had tried that but I must have missed it.  I feel dumb asking, but why would `[i for i in foo.__dict__.items()]` work then? Is it implicitly calling the `iter` on the `.items()`? I had stepped away from Python for a while so feeling a bit lacking.

Comment: @Idlehands Correct. `for` calls `iter` on the iterable you give it.